# Why is Krishna/Vishnu's viswarUpa so fierce?

Tags: vishnu, krishna, bhagavad-gita

I have a very straightforward question. This is pertaining to the ViswarUpa displayed by Krishna to Arjuna in the course of the Bhagavad Gita. Krishna/Vishnu is a shAnta and soumya roopa, a very benevolent God. Why then is his ViswarUpa so fierce that even a brave warrior like Arjuna got scared? I am assuming most people here know this episode, so I am not giving any references from the Gita. That the ViswarUpa was fierce and Arjuna got scared on seeing it, is well-known. The question is - Why is a very benevolent God's Viswarupa so fierce?

PS: Please do not bother giving answers like - ViswarUpa is not actually Krishna/Vishnu but some other god xyz. Also please dont convert this into a Vishnu/Krishna vs other gods thing. Further, please dont convert this into Krishna vs Vishnu thing. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Are referring to slokas in chapter 11 of BG , especially BG 11.30? @Lazy Lubber

Comment: @srimannarayanakv yes and also 11.45. It is interesting to note that Utanka sees the same Viswarupa in Ashwamedhika parva and has a different reaction. But I think you have already answered the question elsewhere as I mention. :)

Comment: Thanks.  That was why I queried, before answering, as BG 11.7 answers many questions.@Lazy Lubber

Comment: @srimannarayanakv Thanks to you actually. Today I really learned something new.

Comment: @srimannarayanakv So also, sage Narada sees a very shAnta Viswarupa in Shanti parva. It all falls into place by that single phrase यच्चान्यद्द्रष्टुमिच्छसि. Simply amazing! Please accept my humble namaskaarams.

Comment: Let me transfer your salutations to Sri Ramana Maharshi, from whose saying, I had learnt about viswarupa :-) @Lazy Lubber

Comment: @srimannarayanakv Yes, my humble namaskaarams to Sri Ramana Maharshi. 

Comment: Do you know Shiva also has a ViswarUpa shown to Rama?